# Error occur in HIve Configuration

Tags: hadoop, hive

### Scenario:

During Hive COnfiguration, when I enter 
hive-dir-path$ bin/hive, I get the error as:
Missing Hive Builtins Jar.

### Description:

After successfully building the package through ant,
when I try for the launching Hive CLI from Hive directory.
I am getting "Missing Hive Builtins Jar: /home/hadoop/hive-0.7.1/hive/lib/hive-builtins-*.jar"

What could be the problem in configuration? Pls suggest me as soon as possible.

Comment: Can you post the way you configured Hive ?  Show the .bash_profile or .bashrc file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you the steps that I followed in configuring Hive

1. Installed hive-0.7.1-cdh3u1 from [Cloudera Repository](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/)
2. Added these 2 lines in .bash_profile

   export HIVE_HOME=/home/hadoop/Desktop/Cloudera/hive-0.7.1-cdh3u1

   export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin

[HIVE_HOME = Path where hive is installed ]

[optional : Running Hive CLI directly without entering the bin folder]

3.Save the file and type source ~/.bash_profile

In my opinion, all jars are available in lib directory. But as you are facing "Missing jars...", you can download those jars.

Still, **hive-0.7.1-cdh3u1** version has all jars in its lib directory.

Answer (score 1):

I got that error once when trying to execute Hive in the bin/ directory. Unless you changed it, Ant might have built Hive in the build/dist/bin directory. The jar files are downloaded to build/dist/lib directory.
This might be why you get a library not found error, even though you got a successful build.